# ImportError: DLL load failed while importing error: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, anaconda3

I get this error when i try to open jupyter notebook using my anaconda command prompt. my anaconda navigator does not open as as well.
I tried uninstalling anaconda, deleting all the relevant files and re-installing it. i tried updating conda and anaconda using command prompt but nothing works.

Comment: Can you try `conda install -c conda-forge notebook` from terminal/cmd?